# Webscrape - How to do pagination when there is no page number in HTML?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pagination

This is the webpage I am trying to scrape: https://www.mecca.com.au/skin-care/

I plan to to scrape the product's
i) brand;
ii) name;
iii) ingredient list

With the below code into a CSV file

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


baseurl = "https://www.mecca.com.au/skin-care/"

productlinks = []

response = requests.get('https://www.mecca.com.au/skin-care/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
products = soup.find_all('div', class_="grid-product-info")

for item in products:
    for link in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        productlinks.append(baseurl + link['href'])

for link in productlinks:
    response = requests.get(link)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")
    brand = soup.find('a', class_='css-1p371np-size5-size5-sansSerif-sansSerif-brandNameLink').text 
    name = soup.find('span', class_='css-1noela6-paragraph-paragraph-sansSerif-sansSerif-productName').text
    print(brand, name)
    for div in soup.find_all('div'):
        if div.text.strip().startswith('Ingredients') and div.text.strip().split(' ')[0] != 'Ingredients':
            print(div.text.strip())
```

I have previously been able to scrape pages when the HTML has pg1, 2, 3 etc with f-strings
But this website loads 36 new products with each page, so the URL constantly changes by numbers of 36

I tried inspecting the buttons for page 2, 3, 4, 5, 'next' on the website, but the links don't have a class to it apart from < li > ...

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Although I did find out I could change the website URL to show the first 2000 products and scrape that way: https://www.mecca.com.au/skin-care/#start=0&sz=2000
But I would love to learn how to do it via code properly!

Answer (score 1):

To get info from more pages you can use their Ajax pagination API, e.g.:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.mecca.com.au/skin-care/"
params = {"start": "0", "sz": "36", "format": "ajax"}


for params["start"] in range(0, 36 * 3, 36):  # <-- increase how many pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, params=params).content, "html.parser")

    for p in soup.select(".grid-product-info"):
        brand = p.select_one(".grid-product-name")
        name = p.select_one(".grid-product-description")

        print(f"{brand.get_text(strip=True):<30} {name.get_text(strip=True)}")
```

Prints:

```
...

Clinique                       Take the Day Off Cleansing Balm
Glow Recipe                    Blueberry Bounce Gentle Cleanser
Tatcha                         Fukubukuro Set 2
Drunk Elephant                 A-Passioni™ Retinol Cream
Sunday Riley                   Go To Bed With Me - Complete Evening Routine Kit
Glow Recipe                    Plum Plump Hyaluronic Cream
```